# Rails asset pipeline - referencing vendor/lib plugin manifest files from the application manifest files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

**THEORY**

The rails guides say you can do something like this

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

> 2.2.2 Using Index Files
>
> Sprockets uses files named index (with the relevant extensions) for a
>   special purpose.
>
> For example, if you have a jQuery library with many modules, which is
>   stored in lib/assets/library_name, the file
>   lib/assets/library_name/index.js serves as the manifest for all files
>   in this library. This file could include a list of all the required
>   files in order, or a simple require_tree directive.
>
> The library as a whole can be accessed in the application manifest
>   like so: //= require library_name
>
> This simplifies maintenance and keeps things clean by allowing related
>   code to be grouped before inclusion elsewhere.

---

**ERROR**

So I'm trying to have manifest files for a plugin in my vendor folder.
But it's not working, saying  in the browser

> couldn't find file 'multipurpose_bookshelf'

---

**CODE**

This originates from my application.js manifest file

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require multipurpose_bookshelf
```

which according to the rails guides, should reference the folder named `multipurpose_bookshelf` rather rather than look for a `multipurpose_bookshelf.js` file in the normal asset paths under the javascripts folder.

The same should be true for css files

**app/assets/javascripts/application.css.scss**

```
/*= require multipurpose_bookshelf
*/
```

should reference the `index.js` or `index.css` files, respectively, in these locations

**vendor/assets/multipurpose_bookshelf/multipurpose_bookshelf.index.js**

```
//= require js/jquery.bookshelf_slider.min
//= require js/easing.1.3
//= require js/
//= require js/ex_skin02
```

**vendor/assets/multipurpose_bookshelf/multipurpose_bookshelf.index.css**

```
/*
 *= require bookshelf_slider
 *= require skin02
 *
 */
```

What am I missing? How do I get my application manifest file to correctly reference my vendor manifest files?

Comment: a workaround.
http://climber2002.github.io/blog/2014/08/17/using-index-files-in-rails-4-assets-pipeline/